# Next13 how apply 'use client' to 'loading.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I wrote a lottie compoent in loading.js

I use App router (Next13)

lottie component

```
import { Player } from '@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player';

import LoadingLottie from '@/assets/loading.json';

function LoginLoadingComponent() {
  return (
    <Player
      loop
      src={LoadingLottie}
      autoplay
      style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px' }}
    />
  );
}
```

loading.tsx

```
'use client';

function loading() {
  console.log('test');
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginLoadingComponent />

      <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl text-center">채널 분석 중 로딩로딩</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to use '@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player' library in my loading time..

but lottie component didn`t apply 'use client'

I don't know what else is there to do....

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'use client' on top of your `LoginLoadingComponent` should be enough as far as client side component is concerned. In case you are getting any specific errors, please update your question accordingly.